# Получить ноды в блоке div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть примерно такой костяк разметки :

```
<div>
<input name="Educations[0].Facultet"/>
<input/>
//...
</div>
```

Как мне получить и изменить атрибут одного из  `input` ?

UPD - блок `div` при первой загрузке страницы всего один. Однако по нажатию ЛКМ на кнопку в документ добавляется еще один. В новом блоке `div` нужно поменять `Educations[0].Facultet` на `Educations[1].Facultet`. И в каждом новом `div` счетчик должен увеличиваться на 1. 
Новый блок `div` добавляется так :

```
var non_ness = document.getElementById('not_necessery_prop');
var cloneNotNess = non_ness.cloneNode(true);
maindiv.appendChild(cloneNotNess);
```

Comment: Обычно у инпутов всегда есть name, по нему и достают стандартными функциями для работы с DOM, описанными в любом учебнике по JS

Comment: @andreymal дело в том, что div добавляется динамически а имена как раз и нужно поменять.

Comment: Тогда опишите задачу полнее и точнее в тексте вопроса (как именно добавляется div, например), а то пока ваши проблемы не очень понятны

Comment: @andreymal дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function showInputValues() {
  var v3 = document.querySelector("input[name='Educations[3].Facultet']").value;
  var v1 = document.querySelector("input[name='Educations[1].Facultet']").value;
  var v0 = document.querySelector("input[name='Educations[0].Facultet']").value;
  console.log(v0, v1, v3);
}
```

```html
<div>
<input name="Educations[0].Facultet" value="a"/>
<input name="Educations[1].Facultet" value="b"/>
<input name="Educations[3].Facultet" value="c"/>
</div>
<button onclick="showInputValues()">Click</button>
```

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку в документ через `cloneNode` копируется еще один такой же `div` с 2 `input`. в новом блоке старые имена инпутов и их нужно изменить.

Comment: хотя ваш ответ помог разобраться.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var i = 1;

function addNode(nodeID,targetID) {
  i++;
  var non_ness = document.getElementById(targetID);
  var maindiv = document.getElementById(nodeID);
  var cloneNotNess = non_ness.cloneNode(true);
  cloneNotNess.id = cloneNotNess.id + i;
  cloneNotNess.children[0].id += i;
  var iname = cloneNotNess.children[0].name;
  iname = iname.replace("[0]", "[" + i + "]");
  console.log(iname);
  maindiv.appendChild(cloneNotNess);
}
```

```html
<button id="knopka" onclick="addNode('maindiv','not_necessery_prop');">knopka</button>
<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="not_necessery_prop">
    <input id="input" type="text" name="Educations[0].Facultet" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно вот так попробовать.

```js
class InputNode {
  static createInput(index, value = '') {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.name = `Educations[${index}].Facultet`;
    input.value = value;

    return input;
  }
  constructor(index) {
    this.elementAll = [
      InputNode.createInput(index, `value_${index++}`),
      InputNode.createInput(index, `value_${index++}`),
      InputNode.createInput(index, `value_${index++}`),
    ]
  }
}

class Count {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

  getCount() {
    let count = this.count;
    this.count += 3;

    return count;
  }
}

let count = new Count();

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let main = document.querySelector('main');

  let inputNode = new InputNode(count.getCount());

  inputNode.elementAll.forEach(element => main.appendChild(element));
});
```

```html
<main></main>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//получаем основной костяк
var S = document.getElementById('s'),
    n=0;
function ND(){
//клонируем его
var cloneS = S.cloneNode(true);
//вставляем перед кнопкой
document.body.insertBefore(cloneS,document.getElementById("btn"));
//заменяем input-потомуку клона value (это для примера, вы можете и name и что угодно менять) 
cloneS.querySelector("input").value=++n;
}
```

```html
<div id="s">
<input value="0">
</input>
</div>
<button id="btn" onmousedown="ND();">new div</button>
```

Comment: Все молодцы, всем по тысяче очков.

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант

```
var maindiv = document.getElementById('maindiv');
var div = document.getElementById('div');

var click = 0;

function create() {
  var cloneDiv = div.cloneNode(true);
  click++;
  var name = "Educations[" + click + "].Facultet";
  maindiv.appendChild(cloneDiv);
  cloneDiv.setAttribute('id','cloneDiv'+ click);
  cloneDiv.children[0].name = name;
}



<div id="maindiv">
  <div id="div">
    <input type="text" name="Educations[0].Facultet">
   </div>
</div>

<button onclick="create()">Create Node</button>
```

Если несколько input'ов, можно сделать так:

```
var arr = [].slice.call(cloneDiv.children,this);
arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.name = name;
});
```